# Failed to execute 'npm run dist' at command (node build/build-plugins.js) loader.js:775 MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, npm

I'm currently following a tooling setup from Bootstrap but I'm really having a hard time trying to understand this.

This is the source of the step-by-step process (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/build-tools/)

Currently, I'm able to run npm scripts (e.g. npm run dist - according to the package.json file from Bootstrap)

During the command ('npm run dist') there's a command being executed as:
node build/build-plugins.js (My Bootstrap root folder doesn't have any build folder!)

Here's the log (using Git Bash - Windows)

```
> bootstrap@4.3.1 js-compile-plugins C:\Workspace\risco-operacional\RiscoOperacional\packages\bootstrap.4.3.1
> node build/build-plugins.js


> bootstrap@4.3.1 css-compile-docs C:\Workspace\risco-operacional\RiscoOperacional\packages\bootstrap.4.3.1
> cross-env-shell node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 site/docs/$npm_package_version_short/assets/scss/docs.scss site/docs/$npm_package_version_short/assets/css/docs.min.css


> bootstrap@4.3.1 js-compile-plugins-coverage C:\Workspace\risco-operacional\RiscoOperacional\packages\bootstrap.4.3.1
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test node build/build-plugins.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Workspace\risco-operacional\RiscoOperacional\packages\bootstrap.4.3.1\build\build-plugins.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bootstrap@4.3.1 js-compile-plugins-coverage: `cross-env NODE_ENV=test node build/build-plugins.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.3.1 js-compile-plugins-coverage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\srebelo001\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-01T13_54_39_217Z-debug.log
fs.js:127
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Workspace\risco-operacional\RiscoOperacional\packages\bootstrap.4.3.1\build'
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1512:7)
    at runRollup (C:\Users\srebelo001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\bin\rollup:1312:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\srebelo001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\bin\rollup:1363:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Workspace\\risco-operacional\\RiscoOperacional\\packages\\bootstrap.4.3.1\\build'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bootstrap@4.3.1 js-compile-bundle: `rollup --environment BUNDLE:true --config build/rollup.config.js --sourcemap`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.3.1 js-compile-bundle script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\srebelo001\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-01T13_54_39_354Z-debug.log
ERROR: "js-compile-plugins-coverage" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bootstrap@4.3.1 js-compile: `npm-run-all --parallel js-compile-* --sequential js-copy`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.3.1 js-compile script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\srebelo001\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-01T13_54_39_938Z-debug.log
ERROR: "js-compile" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bootstrap@4.3.1 js: `npm-run-all js-compile js-minify js-copy`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.3.1 js script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\srebelo001\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-01T13_54_39_973Z-debug.log
ERROR: "js" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bootstrap@4.3.1 dist: `npm-run-all --parallel css js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.3.1 dist script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\srebelo001\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-01T13_54_40_318Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propably ran `npm install bootstrap` command to download the source code of Bootstrap so you're missing `build` folder.

Try to download the source code with Composer. These steps worked for me:

1. `composer require twbs/bootstrap:4.5.0`
2. `cd .\vendor\twbs\bootstrap\`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm run dist`

*(Evn.: Windows 10 + PowerShell, installed npm, node.js, [Ruby+Devkit](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) with Bundler and [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/))*

Recommended instructions: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/build-tools/